# Vertical align breaks my centered div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

When I try to vertical align centered inner DIV my centering isn't working...

What's my problem here?

CSS Code:

```
#page_bar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white
}

.page_bar
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="page_bar">
    <div class="page_bar">
        Mapa Strony
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I want inner DIV to be centered, not the text in inner DIV...

EDIT: Look at: http://mistic-miners.comule.com/index.html the silver area must be centered which means the inner div must be centered not the text inside of inner div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to wrap the .page_bar class in order to get it to center horizontally with the table-cell display.

```
#wrap{
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:table;
}

#page_bar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white
}

.page_bar
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

<div id="page_bar">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="page_bar">
            Mapa Strony
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Is this same as your example above? I tried it and it didn't work... :P Thank  you!

Comment: I used my code from the sample above, but it looked like there were a few other issues with the code on the posted website which interfered with the above code. I made a couple adjustments to the code in JsFiddle, so hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will be centered vertically and horizontally:

```
#page_bar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.page_bar
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgwwB/2/

Answer (score 1):

if you add `text-align:center;` to `#page_bar` ?

Comment: you forgot to add `;` to `background-color: white`

Comment: The last setting in each of styles doesn't require closing ';' since there's '}' right after the setting.

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align: middle

I think you forgot a ';' on this. Also give 2~3px space 30-27 or 33-30

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue and after wasted time on faffing about I finally found the obvious simple fix.

If you apply `'display:table-cell'` to an **element**, apply `'display:table'` to the **parent**, this will make vertical aligning work the way you expect it to.